# Why certificate is needed for signing instead of just private/public key pair?

Tags: security, certificate, x509certificate

Newbie question: some vendors propose solution like generating dynamic certificates  to allow user who haven't classic certificate to sign documents. But why not just generate private/public keys alone instead of bothering with certificate format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the (public key) certificate is to bind the public key to the identity of its subject (i.e. the owner/entity associated with the key pair), and possibly various attributes telling you what the certificate may be used for. (You may be interested in [this question on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14486/2435).)

You always sign with the private key (not the public key or the certificate), but the public key or certificate are often attached with the signed document.

If you have an explicit list of public keys you know and can link independently to a user, you don't need a certificate.

The certificate allows third parties (who have signed the certificate) to assert the binding between the identifier and the public key. Even if you don't know that identity in advance, you can link the signature to the signer's identity as long as you trust the entity that signed the certificate.

Dynamically generated certificates may not be very useful in this case, unless you trust the party that generates the certificate dynamically (I'm not sure if you meant the tool itself or perhaps a website that you would also know).

Often, X.509 certificates will be used just to attach to that signature, because the tooling requires it, whereas you may be able to match the public key against an identity you know directly in the tool with which you verify the signature. Sometimes, it's also just done in anticipation of a case where it will be useful one day.

For example, if you publish your own artifacts to the central Maven repository, you will be required to sign it with your PGP certificate (often only referred to as the PGP public key). Yet, no verification of the certificate is made at all during the process (PGP certificate with only its self-signed signature is good enough). This makes this process relatively pointless in this case, but makes it possible to be stricter in which artifacts you want to use, if you're able to verify those certificates later on.

Comment: They use java api to sign so maybe yes it's for tooling.

Comment: `You always sign with the private key (not the public key or the certificate)`. While this is true most of the time, there are certain situations where you need to sign with public key so that you're sure that 1. the message will be read only by recipient and 2. the message is coming from the person you think it's coming from. So you sign with your private key then sign with public key of the recipient before sending the message.

Comment: @abdelsaid: what I'm saying is that only the private key is involved in the signature operation. The public key is used to verify that signature, not to sign. "*1. the message will be read only by recipient*": here you *encrypt* with the recipient's public key, you don't sign.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same but you need a third party to consent that private key belongs to whom ever you think it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Signing proves first of all authorship (or approval) of the document by some person. And the key alone won't prove anything. This is what the certificate is needed for - some certificate authority signs the certificate of the user and certifies that the keypair belongs to the person (or legal entity) to which the certificate is issued. The reader of the document can ensure that the signature is valid not by just computing the signature itself, but also by validating the certificate and seeing the name of the certificate owner.

I don't quite understand what vendors can issue certificates dynamically - issuing certificate in such way that they are not self-signed (and self-signed certificates make little sense in context of document signing) requires that the private key, used for signing the certificate, should be embedded into software of those vendors, and as such it's also prone to misuse.

Comment: "requires that the private key, used for signing the certificate, should be embedded into software of those vendors, and as such it's also prone to misuse.": the certificate in that case is just used once I guess it's similar to OTP as far as I understand :)

Comment: @user310291 you see, when the document is signed by end-entity certificate, this certificate needs to be signed by some "CA" certificate, otherwise the reader won't be able to validate it. And then the question is how to ensure that CA certificate (it's private key which is supposedly built into some software) is not compromised. The end-entity certificate can be "one-time" but CA certificate can not.